# Blazor not updating ordered list even when StateHasChangedIsCalled

Tags: c#, blazor

I implemented sortable.js with Blazor and I spent way to much time trying to figure out why ordering is not working. In short, after sorting Blazor code is called, sorting is made (correctly, I see it in debugger) but for some reason list is not updated since OrderIndex of elements in list where changed.
Here is code:

```
     window.initializeSortable = (container, blazorComponent, items, 
  options) => {

      const common = {
          onEnd: async function (evt) {
              await blazorComponent.invokeMethodAsync('UpdateItemOrder', evt.oldIndex, evt.newIndex);
           
        },
        
    };
  
     const init = Object.assign({}, options, common);
     if (container != null) {
         Sortable.create(container, init);
         container.__blazor_component = blazorComponent;
     }
    
 };
```

This is my BlazorSortable component:

```
<div @ref="_dropZoneContainer" class="@Class">
@foreach (var item in Items.OrderBy(x => x.OrderIndex))
{
    <div>
        <i class="oi oi-move handle">@item.OrderIndex</i>
    </div>
}
</div>
```

This is relevant part of BlazorSortable code:

```
         public async Task InitializeSortableInJavascript()
        {
          await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("initializeSortable", _dropZoneContainer, DotNetObjectReference.Create(this), Items, Options);
     }

       [JSInvokable]
       public async Task UpdateItemOrder(int oldIndex, int newIndex)
      {
        await OnSortChanged.InvokeAsync(new SortChangedArgs(oldIndex, 
  newIndex));
       
    }


     protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            await Task.Delay(100);
            await InitializeSortableInJavascript();
        }

    }
```

This is how I call component:

```
<BlazorSortable OnSortChanged="@OnSort"
               
                        Class="list-group-sortable-ver-groups"
                        Items="ViewModel.VerificationItems"
                        Options="_options">
                
            </BlazorSortable>
```

and this is OnSort method:

```
      public async Task OnSort(SortChangedArgs sortChangedArgs)
    {
         ViewModel.DisableSorting = true;
StateHasChanged();
            ViewModel.VerificationItems = ViewModel.VerificationItems.OrderBy(x => x.OrderIndex).ToList();

       
        ViewModel.DisableSorting = false;
        StateHasChanged();
     }
```

As can you see I made code as simple as possible to try to find where is problem:  ViewModel.VerificationItems is just ordered in code by index

What I was expecting that list will be rerendered but nothing happened.

C# is method is called successfully, seems nothing strange. Even OnAfterRenderAsync of BlazorSortable is called but elements in DOM are not ordered after I was reorderd them in DOM with sortable.js

Comment: What part of your code do you believe should be changing the order of items in Blazor?